# Shut down list of servers given in a file

Tags: bash, ssh, scripts

I have a list of 17 servers in this format

```
172.16.1.4      #servername-A
172.16.2.75     #servername-B
172.16.5.53     #servername-C
172.16.5.61     #servername-D
```

i'd like a script that can ssh/login to each and every of these servers and shut them down which is easy enough but the catch is that they need to be turned off in a particular order shown above (down the list) where each preceding one has to be completely turned off before the next shut down begins.

Comment: Would it be possible to insert a shutdown hook on all of these machines (except the last)? That would be the safest bet to assert, that they're brought down (almost) completely, before shutting down the next in line. "almost" means, that there is no way to tell remotely, whether a machine is running, after its network is shut down.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps:

```
while read ip rest_of_line; do
    ssh user@$ip sudo poweroff
done < server.file
```

The ssh command will return when the ssh daemon on the remote server is shut down. This is not when the machine is powered off. You might want to add a `sleep` command following the `ssh` command.

Your user should be configured to do `sudo poweroff` without having to provide a password. See the `visudo`
man page.

Comment: Could it help to put a loop behind the command that pings every `n` seconds and breaks when no reply is received within `k` seconds?

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer: I would [edit] that in if Glenn doesn't do that, or post your own even more perfect answer!  **;-)**